# How can I best flatten a nested list to a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, json, purrr, rjson

I would like to convert information from a rest api, which comes in form of json, to a data.frame. The list is nested and theoretically I could repeatedly call purrr::flatten() to get to the bottom of the list and then extract the information using for example purrr:::map_dfr and magrittr:::extract. However, this is very domain specific and doesn't work nicely when extracting information from multiple "hierarchies". I have the following set-up in R:

```
library(rjson)

url <- "https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/SearchServer?searchText=Avenue de Lavaux 63, 1009 Pully&origins=address&type=locations"
result <- rjson::fromJSON(file = URLencode(url))
```

Two questions arise:

1. How can I nicely extract attributes like detail, x and y and write them to a data.frame?
2. On top of that, how can I directly extract values by their names. That is how to extract the values for weight, x, y, and detail.

Thank you very much.

Comment: also try `unlist(result)`

Comment: @ RAB Yes, sorry for that. I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unlist the result and extract x and y like this:

```
res <- unlist(result)
res['results.attrs.x']
# results.attrs.x 
#  "151398.09375"

res['results.attrs.y']
# results.attrs.y 
#  "540429.3125"
```

You can get the names of all other values like this:

```
names(res)
#[1] "results.id"  "results.weight"  "results.attrs.origin"         
#    "results.attrs.geom_quadindex" "results.attrs.zoomlevel"     
#[6] "results.attrs.featureId" "results.attrs.lon" "results.attrs.detail"   
#    "results.attrs.rank" "results.attrs.geom_st_box2d" "results.attrs.lat"
#    "results.attrs.num" "results.attrs.y" "results.attrs.x"  "results.attrs.label"
```

Then you can combine them in a dataframe:

```
res_df <- data.frame(
  X = res['results.attrs.x'],
  Y = res['results.attrs.y']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `unlist` it too. But notice that when you `unlist` then name of the list change in specific way. For example, `result$results[[1]]$id` becomes `results.id` , `result$results[[1]]$weight` becomes `results.weight`. We can use this property to define keys of interest and extract them in separate list using `lapply`. We can then convert the list into separate dataframe.

```
result1 <- unlist(result)
keys <- c("detail", "x", "y", "weight")

df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(keys, function(x) 
          unname(result1[grepl(paste0("\\.", x), names(result1))])))
names(df1) <- values

df1
#                                           detail            x           y weight
#1 avenue de lavaux 63 1009 pully 5590 pully ch vd 151398.09375 540429.3125      7
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Thank you very much for your reply. That was one concern I had (and didn't specifically mention). I will gladly use your approach.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier, and more useful, to extract all of the data. This gets around the problem of the long variable names by simply extracting the names to a new data frame variable, spreading the attributes using these names, and then unnesting the values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(result$results[[1]]) %>% 
    mutate(attr_names = names(attrs)) %>% 
    spread(attr_names, attrs) %>% 
    unnest()
```

Which will return a data frame like the following:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 15
       id weight detail  featureId geom_quadindex geom_st_box2d  label   lat   lon   num origin  rank      x      y zoomlevel
    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>          <chr>          <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2172570      7 avenue… 785542_0  0212222220211… BOX(540429.29… Aven…  46.5  6.66    63 addre…     7 1.51e5 5.40e5        10
```

Comment: Thank you gersht. That's a beautiful solution and even better since I prefer to use dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

Based on and inspired from your answers, I use the following pipe now

```
library(tidyverse)

result %>%
   pluck("results", 1) %>%
   flatten() %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   select(id, weight, detail, x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: not a direct answer to the question, but I think it is a generally helpfull approach.

I was researching this question the last couple of days. I think the best solution is the unlist(). This is not dependant on the nesting and preserves names.

```
library(tidyverse)
result %>% unlist() %>% 
tibble(names = names(.), values = .) %>% # take names as column in tibble
mutate(
    n_seps = str_count(names, "\\.") # count separators to separate to unknown number of columns
) %>%
separate(names,str_c(
        "col_",
        c(1:(max(.$n_seps) +1)
        )), sep = "\\."
        ) %>% 
select(-n_seps)
```

Only caveat is that if the column names already contain ".", this will add a nesting level per ".". I found a solution to rename lists recursively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63075776/14604591.

output:

```r
result <- rjson::fromJSON(file = "c:/Users/elshikh/Downloads/SearchServer.json")


mydailyhelpers::tidy_nested_lists(result)
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1, 2].
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    col_1   col_2  col_3          values                                         
#>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>          <chr>                                          
#>  1 results id     <NA>           2692129                                        
#>  2 results weight <NA>           1                                              
#>  3 results attrs  origin         address                                        
#>  4 results attrs  geom_quadindex 021222222021110121000                          
#>  5 results attrs  zoomlevel      10                                             
#>  6 results attrs  featureId      785542_0                                       
#>  7 results attrs  lon            6.66245317459106                               
#>  8 results attrs  detail         avenue de lavaux 63 1009 pully 5590 pully ch vd
#>  9 results attrs  rank           7                                              
#> 10 results attrs  geom_st_box2d  BOX(540428.897 151398.511999999,540428.897 151~
#> 11 results attrs  lat            46.5112342834473                               
#> 12 results attrs  num            63                                             
#> 13 results attrs  y              540428.875                                     
#> 14 results attrs  x              151398.515625                                  
#> 15 results attrs  label          Avenue de Lavaux 63 <b>1009 Pully</b>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>